# In macOS how to use samba from homebrew instead of the system default smb

Tags: macos, cifs

I got a wifi router connected with ssd drive shared across network. From my Linux machine connected over wifi, to copy a 956MB file to the network share mounted with `mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pass,vers=1.0 //192.168.0.1/Lake /mnt/Lake/`, it took 2min52s.

From my Mac, connected directly to the WiFi router using ethernet cable(usb-to-ethernet), to transfer the same file to the same network share, connected with smbfs, it took 3m12s. it took 20s more despite being connected using ethernet cable.

Is it my usb to ethernet cable slowing down? Or is smbfs?

I've installed `samba` from `homebrew`, how to mount the network share using it? `-t cifs` says `/Library/Filesystems/cifs.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_cifs` not there.

Comment: Try the solutions from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/can-not-use-mount-cifs-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: @harrymc, that's for linux, I'm on macOS!

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some macOS equivalents.

Comment: that's what I want